# How to remove duplicated elements in lists using list_data.count?

Tags: python, list

```
def number_of_cases(list_data):
    result = []

    for i in list_data:
        for j in list_data:
            result.append(str(i) + str(j))

    return result

print(number_of_cases(['a', 'b', '1', '2']))
```

Whatever I input as the `list_data` argument, I want to get a deduplicated list of number of cases. But when the argument is `['a', 'a']`, I get `['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa']`, not `['aa']`. How do I remove duplicated elements in a list while preserving their order **using list_data.count()** (because this is homework)?

Comment: I've been searching for a while, but couldn't find the exact answer I want

Comment: Titus Yun: Why do you have to use `list.count()`? Homework?

Comment: Yes, I've been stuck on this for three hours. this got me to sign in this website. Thanks for the editing.

Comment: Titus Yun: Although you mention `list.count` in the title, the last sentence of your question doesn't. Fix that and mention it's homework, and I'll vote to reopen your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is my first post I put on here. I'll keep in mind that. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Note I added a `dedup` keyword argument with a default value of `True` only to make testing easy (feel free to remove it).

The tricky part is it needs to go through the elements in `result` backwards, so the indexes of elements it hasn't looked at yet don't change each time one is deleted.

Another way to think about is, by going backwards through the initial `result`, if it sees something that occurs more than once, it can assume there's another one occurring *earlier* in the list and can safely delete the current one.

```
def number_of_cases(list_data, dedup=True):
    result = []

    for i in list_data:
        for j in list_data:
            result.append(str(i) + str(j))

    if dedup:
        # remove duplicates
        for i in range(len(result)-1, 0, -1):
            if result.count(result[i]) > 1:
                del result[i]

    return result

print(number_of_cases(['a', 'a', 'b'], dedup=False))
print(number_of_cases(['a', 'a', 'b']))  # will dedup by default
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'aa', 'ab', 'aa', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'ba', 'bb']
['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. This "trick" is generally a good thing to know and remember because the need to use it occurs fairly often when modifying sequences.